# Where can I find more information on the Federated Malay States V.F.?

Tags: world-war-two, military, british-empire, malaysia, colonial

badge has a crown on top with a shield in the middle. slider on back on front reads Federated Malay States V.F. I was wondering if anyone knows much about the badge as I have not found out much about it.[image]

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: Please include a picture, in as high a resolution as possible in order to allow discernment of fine detail.

Comment: Does it look like anything here: https://www.malayanvolunteersgroup.org.uk/miscellaneous--historic-photos.html ?

Comment: Does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_Malay_States) help?

Answer (score 4):

More for users on this SE since OP has not included an image, here’s the insignia:

[image]

[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:16_Federated_Malay_States_Volunteer_Force_(9062281607).jpg).

As per comments, VF is Volunteer Force of the Federated Malay States. Principally for foreigners (colonialists), not locals, in four states of what is now Malaysia.